# Rspec expect assigns shorthand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have something like:

```
it 'assigns @competition' do
  expect(assigns(:competition)).to be_a_new(Competition)
end
```

Is there a shorter version of this using the `it { should ... }` type syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that it's shorter, but you can use:

```
subject {assigns(:competition)}
it {should be_a_new(Competition)}
```

or you can use:

```
it {expect(assigns(:competition)).to be_a_new(Competition)}
```

In both cases, the shortening is coming from the elimination of the string argument to `it`, which is independent of the use of `should`.

Comment: Yes, although referencing `subject` explicitly is considered a "smell" by RSpec's original author.

Answer (score 2):

By now the RSpec documentation suggests to use `is_expected.to`, as in:

```
describe [1, 2, 3] do
  it { is_expected.to be_an Array }
  it { is_expected.not_to include 4 }
end
```

cf. http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/MemoizedHelpers#is_expected-instance_method

Comment: But how is it used in conjunction with `assigns`?

Comment: Just use `subject {assigns(:competition)}` above or `expect(assigns(:competition))`.

Comment: AFAICT `expect(assigns(:competition))` passes, whether @competition is assigned or not